# White label worker from an outsource agency

Tags: project-management-style

I have an outsourcing agency for IT works. I offered one of our services to some company in west Europe. We offered one guy to work with them as a "cost + material" model.
But the client came back with the following request:

```
Don't you mind if we will work white-label? As [your IT developer] will work on behalf of our company - as our employee on the project?
```

I wonder how would that work? How payments would be made. Is that my developer would be fully employed in that country of the project? Or would he just fully appear in their system as their employee but technically be employed by my company.

Comment: Not sure this is really about managing projects.

Comment: In my experience such arrangements can be just informal. No difference in contractual terms just an understanding that as far as your client's customers are concerned your employee appears to be your client's employee.

Answer (score 1):

This is a model that companies love; they don't have enough headcounts to employ someone, but they have budgets to complete their projects. The solution they use is the one you describe.

Your client will be working directly with that consultant, and you will not be involved in their daily routines. They will come to you when they have a problem with the consultant and replace that consultant.

For time + material agreements, your consultant will fill out a timesheet, the client will approve the timesheet and then pay you.